# Why is my DateTime deserializer is truncating DateTime's minute/second/millisecond?

Tags: java, json, datetime, gson, jodatime

I have a class that `deserializes` a `JSON` element.

```
public class DateTimeConverter implements JsonSerializer<DateTime>, JsonDeserializer<DateTime>
{
    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecondMillis();
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(DateTime src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        final DateTimeFormatter fmt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecondMillis();
        return new JsonPrimitive(fmt.print(src));
    }


    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException
    {
        final String dateAsString = json.getAsString();
        System.out.println(dateAsString);
        if (json.isJsonNull() || dateAsString.length()==0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return DATE_FORMAT.parseDateTime(json.getAsString());
        }
    }
}
```

However, my `Deserialize` method when I input:

```
2015-07-29T11:00:00.000Z
```

I receive:

```
2015-07-29T11
```

from the `System.out.println(dateAsString);` Why is it truncating my input?

I think my issue is within my test class:

I constructed a `DateTime` object to be used with Google's Gson. However, I think the default constructor for `DateTimeType` doesn't support minute/second/millisecond. Is there a way I can extend the `DateTimeType` to support it?

Here is my test class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
/**
 * Tests {@link DateTimeConverter}.
 */
public class DateTimeConverterTest {
    String testTime = "2015-07-29T11:00:00.001Z";

    @Test
    public void testDateTimeConverter() throws Exception {
        final Gson gson = initCustomGSON();
        Type DateTimeType = new TypeToken<DateTime>() {
        }.getType();

        System.out.println(testTime);
        DateTimeConverter timeConverter = new DateTimeConverter();
        DateTime m = (gson.fromJson(testTime, DateTimeType));

        assertThat("11", is(m.hourOfDay().getAsText()));
    }

    public Gson initCustomGSON() {
        final GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        JodaTimeConverters converter = new JodaTimeConverters();
        converter.registerAll(builder);
        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know too much about GSON to be sure, but perhaps a library like [gson-jodatime-serialisers](https://github.com/gkopff/gson-jodatime-serialisers) could help you?

Comment: Hahaha those are what I am basing my deserializers off of! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84615/discussion-between-tukajo-and-vivin-paliath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues with this code.

1. Your first problem is that `:` is an operator in Json. You are interpreting an unescaped `String` with a `:` in it, so Gson is interpreting it as `key` **:** `value`. Your test string needs to surround the entire text date with quotes to prevent this from happening, e.g.

   ```
   String testTime = "\"2015-07-29T11:00:00.001Z\"";
   ```
2. You were using [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecondMillis()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateHourMinuteSecondMillis()) in your code. However, the format pattern for this is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`, which as you can see does not include a time zone. You want to be using [`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTime()), whose pattern is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`, which does have a time zone.

   ```
   private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
   ```
3. Once these two changes are made, the `DateTime` object is finally properly created... but it will be created in **your** local time zone, not in UTC (it will correctly adjust the time to your zone. You can easily switch this back to UTC by doing:

   ```
   DateTime m = ((DateTime) (gson.fromJson(testTime, DateTimeType))).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
   ```

Once you make these three changes, your tests will pass. **However:** I strongly advise against using `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`, they have been deprecated in favor of [`TypeAdapter`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html), whose streaming API is [significantly more performant:](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html)

> New applications should prefer `TypeAdapter`, whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API.

I am aware the user guide provides code for how to do it with the `JsonSerializer` / `JsonDeserializer` API, but that's just because they haven't yet updated it.

It would simply be something like this:

```
public class DateTimeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<DateTime> {
  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMAT = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();

  public DateTime read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {
    if (reader.peek() == JsonToken.NULL) {
      reader.nextNull();
      return null;
    }
    String dateString = reader.nextString();
    if(dateString.length() == 0) return null;
    return FORMAT.parseDateTime(dateString);
  }

  public void write(JsonWriter writer, DateTime value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
      writer.nullValue();
      return;
    }
    writer.value(FORMAT.print(value));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your suggestions when I get back into the office tomorrow morning :).

Comment: So this approach worked (the initial). But one question I have is if the server is returning the unescaped string is there anyway I can modify that to be acceptable?

Comment: An example data return would be this Json Array:

Comment: `{"roomId":"jYNpbH15Vb","startTime":"2015-07-29T11:00:00.000-0500","endTime":"2015-07-29T12:00:00.000-0500","meetingName":"OSQ Requirements","contactName":"NAME NAME","createdAt":"2015-07-29T07:23:47.269-0500","updatedAt":"2015-07-29T07:23:47.269-0500","objectId":"DaxfYVHkwf"}`

Comment: Correct but I am saying when I return those values it still crashes the program when deserializing. I am wondering if for some reason what you said was being confused is the reason why it is crashing?

Comment: I'm not following you. [Come back in this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84615/discussion-between-tukajo-and-vivin-paliath)